# IE8 jquery find issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have this piece of code, works perfectly in all browswers except IE8 and Chrome

You can choose Yes or NO for each row, this will be like:

html:

```
 <input type="radio" value="1" name="e_male">
<input type="radio" value="0" name="e_male">

a = $($.find("input[name="+ key +"_"+ k +"]:checked")).val();
```

this would look for example:

```
a = $($.find("input[name=e_male]:checked")).val();
```

IE8, 9 and Chrome returns a as 0

**I see now that I had my eyes up my $ and was not seeing the actual problem! this was not the problem, the problem came earlier, but that another question) sorry!**

Comment: The fact that the radio button has value="1" doesn't mean that it is considered checked.

Comment: try adding quotes: `"input[name='e_male']:checked"`

Comment: quotes did not work. in chrome it actualy returns undefined

Comment: I check the buttons with my mouse, I just use the 1 value for other parts.  but they are not seen as checked by chrome and IE

Comment: You should post it as an answer and mark it resolved, if so. (or even delete the question)